# Initialise immutable JPA collection in database

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My domain contains FieldValidator objects, that have sub classes EmailValidator, SizeValidator etc. There is only one instance of FieldValidator per subclass.

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "FIELD_VALIDATOR")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
public abstract class FieldValidator extends AbstractEntity implements IFieldValidator{

    @Column(unique=true, name="TYPE")
    public String type;

    public String name;
    public String argumentName;

    //To override by subclasses
    public abstract Optional<CustomError> run(FieldConstraint constraint);

    /**
    * Constructor, getters and setters omitted
    */
}
```

Example subclass

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DATE_BEFORE")
public class DateBeforeValidator extends FieldValidator {
    public DateBeforeValidator() {
        super("Date", "Before");
    }

    public Optional<CustomError> run(FieldConstraint constraint) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Example subclass

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SIZE_MIN")
public class SizeMinValidator extends FieldValidator {

    public SizeMinValidator() {
        super("Size", "Minimum");
    }

    public Optional<CustomError> run(FieldConstraint constraint) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

How can I initialise the FIELD_VALIDATOR table with one entity per FieldValidator subclass? I need ensure that: the FIELD_VALIDATOR table is immutable (no other data can be added or deleted to/from the table), each FieldValidator entity is unique and immutable (the @Column(unique=true) and the @Immutable annotations should do the trick).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is JPAs/Hibernates initial load feature. You can read about it [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-create-initialize-database/) for example.